# I dont know why HTML file can't load the CSS , even though both are in the same directory. Any idea what might be the problem?

Tags: html

.index file

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Using Internal CSS</title>
 <link href="elliptical shaped.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<p class="one"></p>
<p class="two"></p>
<p class="three"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
.one {
border-top-left-radius: 80px 50px;
-moz-border-radius-top-left: 80px 50px;
-webkit-border-radius-top-left: 80px 50px;}
.two {
border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em / 2em 1em 2em 1em;
-moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em
 / 2em 1em 2em 1em;
-webkit-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em
 / 2em 1em 2em 1em;}
.three {
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;}
```

The browser page is not showing anything even after refreshing it so much.It is just showing a blank space

Comment: The first thing I would do is to rename the css to something without a space in between. And it would help if you showed us something like a directory structure of your files.

Comment: No way to know without the file structure. What do the dev tool console and network tab say? The network tab tells you if it tries to load the CSS file and which code it returns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess, this is due to,
You haven't written any content.
you just created classes.

```
<p class="one">Hello</p>
<p class="two">Stack Over Flow</p>
<p class="three">CSS</p>
```

try this out or write some content between tags
the page won't be blank.